# Apache Camel File2 include only specific subfolders from the source directory

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am using Apache Camel File2 (SFTP) (with Camel Latest version) and Java8 API.
I am trying to develop a MyRouteBuilder.java class which extends RouteBuilder class and implements the configure method.

I want to transfer files from source path to destination path.
Here in the source endpoint, specifying the URI parameter "include" to include files from particular specific subfolders under the source path like "SubFolder1, SubFolder2, SubFolder3".

Example Source URIs:
1) "file:\src\SubFolder1\.*\.txt" 
2) "file:\src\SubFolder2\.*\.txt"

I have tried with the multiple examples below and even 
   Examples:

```
 1) include=.SubFolder[1-2]\.*\.txt
 2) include=.SubFolder1|SubFolder2\.*\.txt
 3) include=SubFolder[1-2]\.*\.txt
 4) include=SubFolder1\.*\.txt
 5) include=.SubFolder(?)\.*\.txt
```

Nothing is working.

Please suggest a way to solve using Apache Camel File2 API using Java.

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    String sftpUrl = "sftp://" + user + "@" + hostName + sourcePath + "?" + "noop=true"
            + "&recursive=true&include=.*\\.txt$"+"&strictHostKeyChecking=no" + "&useUserKnownHostsFile=true" + "&password=RAW("
            + password + ")&preferredAuthentications=publickey,keyboard-interactive,password";  

    System.out.println("\n\n sftpUrl + " + sftpUrl + "\n\n");

    from(sftpUrl)
        .log(" Copying File : ${file:name} ").process(exchange -> {
        System.out.println("1. Processing a File  --> = " + exchange);
    }).to("file://" + destPath)
            // ;
    .log("Uploading file ${file:parent} / ${file:name} complete.");
}
```

Comment: Presuming you have tried examples from the [official docs](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html). Can you show us your route builder code (whatever you have). "Nothing is working" is not a good problem statement. Tell is what exactly is not working

Comment: include parameter regex is not working

Comment: String sftpUrl = "sftp://" + user + "@" + hostName + sourcePath + "?" + "noop=true" + "&recursive=true&include=.SubFolder1\\\\*\\.txt$"+"&strictHostKeyChecking=no" + "&useUserKnownHostsFile=true" + "&password=RAW("
+ password + ")&preferredAuthentications=publickey,keyboard-interactive,password";

Comment: That looks like the [ftp2](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html) component and not File2. FTP2 doesn't support `include`. Please post your whole route in the question not here in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hk6279 indicated below, FTP2 inherits File2 and File2 behaviors are available on FTP2 unless stated otherwise. However, a very important part that OP might have missed out was highlighted by @hk6279.

`Only files (not directories) are matched for valid filename, if options such as: include or exclude are used.`

May be this is what is causing trouble.

---

Looks like you are referring to FTP2 component and not file2 component. Please have a look at the [FTP component's test cases](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-ftp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote) to see how filtering is implemented. <strike>It does not support `include` option as you can see in the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html).</strike>

- [Sample filter test](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/FromFtpFilterTest.java)
- [Another one](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/FromFtpRemoteFileFilterTest.java)

Comment: The ftp2 [docs](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html) does not claim ftp2 component does not support `include` option, but the statement `See File for more options as all the options from File is inherited` exist

Comment: Instead, you should quote this statement `Only files (not directories) are matched for valid filename, if options such as: include or exclude are used.` from file [doc](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Comment: Perhaps that exactly is the issue OP is facing. Got to try this later and see.

Comment: Try with the `antInclude` option as it should support directories (it does so for file component)

Comment: Example :  antInclude=F1/*.txt,F2/*.txt

Answer (score 1):

You should use `antInclude` as it supports both directories and files.
And btw the Camel website is undergoing a complete redesign, and in the mean-time the up-to-date component documentation can be browsed from github.

```
antInclude=F1/*.txt,F2/*.txt
```

So look at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/main/docs/ftp-component.adoc

And also mind you can browser per version documentation (choose branch/tag).

Comment: antInclude uri option is working fine when I am trying to use sftp url. 

But when I am trying to use the below url with "file://" instead of "sftp://", it is not working. 

file://C:/Input?noop=true&recursive=true&antInclude=F1/*.txt,F2/*.txt

Comment: I mean camel is not transfering files from the subfolders F1 and F2 when I use url with "file://"